# Is it possible to provide an url with a POST instruction in a web-link?

Tags: http, url, url-routing

Is it possible to provide an URL with a POST instruction in a web-link?

I'm trying to link to a page that requires the user to select an option from the drop-down, and looking at the source of the page, it appears to POST the selection.

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="roomname">
<option value="+Community">+Community</option>
<option value="2011 Graduates">2011 Graduates</option>
...
</select>
```

I'd like to provide the user with a link to get to the page that preselects the correct option for the user without modifying the system I'm trying to send them to.

Is that possible to do with just an URL? If so, how would one do that?

(I'm pretty sure the system is running Python, not PHP, on the backend.)

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this as being possible, because this would allow all sorts of cross site security issues.

e.g. a POST usually signifies some user action and you don't want it to be an automated action like a GET - i.e. a GET can be done automatically like on images that are requested without the users permissions when viewing a webpage or email.
Having something that is expected to be user initiated like a POST happening automatically would be a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with POST. You can do accomplish this using javascript or the server side language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to perform a `POST` request with a URL link.  Such links always perform a `GET` request instead.

The only way to do what you are asking for is to make the link invoke client-side scripting that navigates to the desired URL and then manipulates the desired `<form>` fields on the new page.  Since you would be navigating to another URL, your script will have to run from a different window/frame then the one that is being navigated.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it looks like it's not provided for in URL specification:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Thanks for the feedback. I'll leave this up in case anyone else has this type of question in the future.